# report viewer doesn't show total pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

Why does the report viewer show "?" instead of the total pages.
how can I force it to calculate the total pages of the report ?

[image]

P.S same happens in the web component of the report viewer control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this suggested solution [see section 'Display Total Number of Pages while Navigating a SSRS Report'](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3023/sql-server-reporting-services-tips-and-tricks-to-improve-the-end-user-experience/)

[This posting suggests the reason](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a7e302d-e518-497e-a2d0-aae095afdb05/ssrs-2008-report-manager-html-viewer-total-pages-not-showing-on-first-pages)